# two or more search datalist once choose value not display in others

Tags: html, laravel-5

two or more search datalist,lists are both same but one search datalist choose value disable to another search datalist.

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">1</option>
    <option value="Firefox">2</option>
    <option value="Chrome">3</option>
    <option value="Opera">4</option>
    <option value="Safari">5</option>
</datalist>

<input list="browsers2" name="browser2">

<datalist id="browsers2">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">1</option>
    <option value="Firefox">2</option>
    <option value="Chrome">3</option>
    <option value="Opera">4</option>  
<option value="Safari">5</option>
</datalist>
```